# Best way to store settings (special requirements)

Tags: c#, architecture, application-settings

I found a lot of information for saving different kinds of application/user settings in different places but getting confused what could be the best way for me.

My problem has different dimensions:

1. The application will have some User-Roles (Admin, StandardUser, ...), where every User (based on Windows-Logon) will belong to one role.
   The Admin is allowed to setup everything for everyone.
2. The settings have different categories:

   - Application settings (should be the same for every user on the computer)
   - User-Role-specific settings
   - User-specific settings
3. The application has several projects where different projects have to access the settings.

(4. The application is written in C#)

I don't want to mention the things that I have read because I don't want to steer your thoughts into a (maybe wrong) direction.
So, how would you handle this scenario?

Thanks a lot!!
Joerg

---

**EDIT 1**

Some more things after the first answers that I hope can clarify my question:

- my question doesn't focus on the authentication of the users, it focusses on create/edit/save settings
- my first attempts for solving the problem were:

  1. using the Visual Studio Settings.Settings file
     ... doesn't work because I have several projects that have to have access to the settings AND I couldn't find a way to make the ApplicationSettings writeable (they are readonly)
  2. use the `ConfigurationManager`-Class
     ... I am not experienced with this one but as far as I understand this class it is just another class that gives me access to my ApplicationSettings (and has the same problems like #1)
     ... maybe a link to a *good* tutorial will help
  3. invent something on my own
     ... I still hope to find something ready-to-use

Comment: FYI, you can make the settings writable by changing the Scope from "Application" to "User".

Comment: I know that but I want that administrators can change options for _every_ user at the computer. If I use "User"-scope it is saved in Users-Folder

Comment: I've updated my answer with a technique you could use to accomplish administrator overrides.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in this kind of scenarios you probably have a database. When you incorporate users, user rights, etc in there it is probably also a good place to save your application settings.

I always love the database centric solutions, since there are widely available (when you want to create a new UI based on the same system, you can reuse the settings there).

I think the entity–attribute–value model is a good design strategy to consider.

You can create a view with triggers on them hiding system only properties, enabling the admin to change all, and the user to only change theirs.

Comment: My application has no database (yet). I would like to avoid this because I have the feeling that it's oversized for the problem...

Comment: Okay, then narrow down your question please to make your current situation clearer.

Comment: If it turns out that a database will be the best solution I will setup one. So I would not generally eliminate the idea. Because I am still in the design stage I wanted to ask an "open" question.

Comment: @joerg: But open question never provide specific answers, which you expect by saying 'I can't do that because...'. Just trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

By your description I'd say you want [Role Based Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rbac). It's something that has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559114/role-based-access-control-for-a-wpf-app-best-practices). I'd go to the [link specified in that answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953196%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) to find an overview and some code samples of how to approach this problem.

Microsoft has done a great job adding some abstractions with the Membership Providers and now the ASP.NET Identity Framework (in case you have a Web Application). Regardless of what you choose to do, database or config files are going to be involved (take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to learn how to manage those) and some sort of [claim derived system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517291.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**: You already have figured out how you are going to handle roles, and your question is only about storage/retrieval of settings.

Point #3 means you can't use a [Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) file for Application and User scoped settings combined with a [custom configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) for holding the role specific settings (optionally [encrypted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

My next suggestion would be a WCF endpoint that exposes the settings, either in their entirety (security trimmed contents of Application + User specific + Role specific) or by some sort of dictionary lookup equivalent. Additionally:

- The endpoint would need to require Windows Authentication (or possibly Claims) so that it could determine the user specific/role specific part.
- Each application would then need to have knowledge of the WCF endpoint, either through configuration or potentially through [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Update**:
Note that WCF doesn't solve your storage question, but it helps with your point #3 - multiple projects that need to use the same settings. A WCF endpoint allows a single project that encapsulates the storage/retrieval of settings to be re-used by multiple clients. WCF can be complicated to read about, but in practice it's pretty easy to setup - you just decorate an interface and host it in IIS. You could also host it yourself in something like a windows service if you were adverse to using IIS, but deploying it to IIS would be a lot easier. You can then consume it in your other applications by adding a Service Reference to your project, and then you call the interface code as if the code was in your own project.

**In case you are talking about a single application with multiple class libraries:**

What I'm describing above assumes you are making multiple applications that all need to share settings. If you are actually talking about a single application with multiple class library projects, the built-in Settings can still be used - there is just one manual step you need to do to make it work across projects. After adding settings to both your application project and your class library project(s), you should copy the app.config section containing the settings in your class library and copy/paste it into your application's app.config. Visual Studio isn't very clever and it will only sync the class library Settings changes to an app.config within the class library project, even though an app.config for a class library isn't a "real thing", since only the app.config for the application consuming the class library is actually used by default (which is why you need to merge it into your application's app.config).

If you need multiple class libraries (including the main application project) to use the same settings, you could make a dedicated class library project just to hold the settings (note you can add multiple Settings files to this project to make the settings more modular), and then all the other projects could reference the common settings project (to avoid circular dependencies, you wouldn't hold any Settings in the main application project that a class library needed).

**Overriding a user's settings**

The Settings object has a mechanism you could use to override settings (say, with value's specified by an administrator). When you add a Settings object to your project, it creates a Settings partial class with some example code for wiring into the SettingsLoaded event. In this event, you could load your administrative settings (either through a WCF call, or perhaps from a know location on the file system) and apply any overrides.

Comment: _Assumption: You already have figured out how you are going to handle roles, and your question is only about storage/retrieval of settings_ Yes, you got it! Will have a look at the WCF (not used before).

Comment: I think WCF isn't a solution on it's own, you will always need an extra solution to save the settings. WCF is just a communication protocol.

Comment: After a short reading about WCF I feel like this is a bit too much for me. Can't Point #3 not be solved with a static class? (I know that doesn't answer the question where the settings are saved)

Comment: Regarding a static class - this makes me think I may have made an incorrect assumption when you said multiple projects. I was assuming you meant multiple applications - are you actually talking about a single application with multiple class library projects?

Comment: FYI, I also forgot to mention I updated my answer in response to the comments about WCF.

Comment: Yes, my application is a single application with multiple projects. So no inter-app-communication... Currently I am on the way to have a static settings-class in a single project (that is referenced by the others) and I use the SettingsManager to save/load settings. I am still reading and try to understand it in depth, this seems to be the most helpful resource: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)